# Iterations of proper forcings defined in an inner model

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Are there any examples where a countable support iteration of proper forcing defined in an inner model does crazy things in an outer model? This is vague, so to narrow it down, are there examples of $V\supset M$ and a countable support iteration of proper forcing $\langle P_i, \dot{Q}_j: i\leq \omega, j<\omega\rangle$ defined in $M$ such that for each $j\in \omega$, $P_j$ is proper in $V$, but $P_\omega$ collapses $\omega_1$ in $V$. Of course, when $V$ and $M$ are sufficiently close (for example $V\models M^\kappa\subset M$ for large enough $\kappa$), the iteration will look the same. Since we are taking countable support iteration, I'll impose that (at least) $V\models M^\omega\subset M$.

Another test question:

> Suppose $V\models M^\omega \subset M$. Is it true that countable support iteration of Cohen forcing defined in $M$ is equivalent to the one defined in $V$?